# How was this old beacon used?

Tags: navigation

I saw this beacon at an old airport; how and in what situations was it used?

[image: Beacon at Ljunbyhed, ESTL]

Comment: Please provide attribution for your image.

Comment: What airport was this seen at? Are there other pictures? Airport beacons are typically White/Green Rotating units and do not have a red light on top. This may however predate modern convention.

Comment: I took this pic myself at Ljungbyhed, Sweden(ESTL). More pics on request ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [airfield identification beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodrome_beacon).

> An aerodrome beacon or rotating beacon is a beacon installed at an
>   airport or aerodrome to indicate its location to aircraft pilots at
>   night.
>
> An aerodrome beacon is mounted on top of a towering structure, often a
>   control tower, above other buildings of the airport. It produces
>   flashes not unlike that of a lighthouse.
>
> Airport and heliport beacons are designed in such a way to make them
>   most effective from one to ten degrees above the horizon; however,
>   they can be seen well above and below this peak spread. The beacon may
>   be an omnidirectional flashing xenon strobe, or it may be an
>   aerobeacon rotating at a constant speed which produces the visual
>   effect of flashes at regular intervals. Flashes may be of just a
>   single color, or of two alternating colors.

Comment: Flyer's version of a lighthouse... except it indicates the port, not a hazard to avoid. I've seen these from above, when in a friend's private plane after dark; they definitely do catch your eye and help you plan your approach.